# Avoid repeated select statement when using "extra" clause in Django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x

I need to be able to retrieve a sum of related records for display purposes, and also order by the sum of the counts of three related models. Currently, I'm solving this by using an "extra" clause:

```
results = Poll.visible.extra(
    select={
        'f_count':
        """
        SELECT COUNT('id') FROM polls_forecast
        WHERE polls_forecast.poll_id = polls_poll.id
        """,
        'total':
        """
        (SELECT COUNT('id') FROM polls_forecast
         WHERE polls_forecast.poll_id = polls_poll.id) +
        (SELECT COUNT('id') FROM polls_pollcomment
         WHERE polls_pollcomment.poll_id = polls_poll.id) +
        (SELECT COUNT('id') FROM polls_favoritedpoll
         WHERE polls_favoritedpoll.poll_id = polls_poll.id)
        """
    }
).order_by('-total')[:100]
```

Is it possible to alias `f_count` so I don't have to do the same count in the `total` select statement? Referencing `f_count` in the `total` select raises a "column does not exist" error.

I'm using Postgres 9.4, Django 1.7.5, Python 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by using `.extra`. You'll need to use `raw`. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/) on it.

If you do decide to go that route, you'll have to do the filter that's involved in `visible` in that raw SQL query as well. I'm not 100% positive on what RawQuerySet provides compared to QuerySet.

Comment: I figured as much, I'm currently working on a raw sql solution to be more efficient. Once I get the query working right, I'll post my answer, but accept yours since it's not possible to avoid the extra query.

Comment: I wonder if you could do them as annotations and then sum them in the extra? So ```Poll.visible.annotate(forecast_count=Count('forecast_set', distinct=True), etc, etc).extra(select={'total': 'sum(col1, col2)'})```

Comment: I decided to just leave the subqueries in place for now. I'll eventually move this tabulation to a scheduled function.